# chrome extension API for refreshing the page

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is there an API to programmatically refresh the current tab from inside a browser action button? I have background page configured, which attaches a listener via:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) { ... });
```

So the callback function retrieves a reference to the tab that it was clicked from, but I don't see an API anywhere to refresh/reload that tab.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I recommend using `chrome.tabs.executeScript` to inject javascript that calls `window.location.reload()` into the current tab. Something like:

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
  var code = 'window.location.reload();';
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {code: code});
});
```

Reference [here](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs)

Comment: chrome.tabs.getSelected() has been deprecated.  [My answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25246060) uses the same basic method, but with the currently accepted way to get the current tab.

Comment: @Boris, Doesn't executeScript already default to the current tab? Then what's the point of doing `chrome.tabs.getSelected`?

Comment: The Answer below (https://stackoverflow.com/a/8933014/187360) which points to the API documentation is the best way to go about this. Perhaps in 2014 the above was the best means to the ends but no longer for today's development cycle.

Answer (score 57):

I think what you're looking for is:

```
chrome.tabs.reload(integer tabId, object reloadProperties, function callback)
```

Check out [tabs API() documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs) for more information.

Comment: If you don't pass any arguments, it'll refresh the the selected tab of the current window.

Answer (score 44):

The API for chrome.tabs.getSelected(), which the accepted answer uses, **has been deprecated**.  You should instead get the current tab and reload it using something like the following:

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function (arrayOfTabs) {
    var code = 'window.location.reload();';
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(arrayOfTabs[0].id, {code: code});
});
```

Or perhaps:

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function (arrayOfTabs) {
    chrome.tabs.reload(arrayOfTabs[0].id);
});
```

I had no real luck with the second version, though other answers seem to suggest it should work.  The API seems to suggest that, too.

Comment: Works for me, but keep getting `extensions::lastError:131 Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabs.executeScript: Cannot access contents of url "https://jsfiddle.net/". Extension manifest must request permission to access this host.`

Comment: @Michael, Doesn't executeScript and tabs.reload already default to the current tab? Then what's the point of doing `chrome.tabs.query`?

Answer (score 9):

More specifically:

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.reload(tab.id);
});
```

Comment: getSelected() has been deprecated

Answer (score 6):

You can also use this:

```
chrome.tabs.reload(function(){});
```

> reload function params:  integer tabId, object reloadProperties,
> function callback

Reference: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-reload

Answer (score 0):

> if you want to reload all the tabs which have loaded completely and are active in their window

```
chrome.tabs.query({status:'complete'}, (tabs)=>{
tabs.forEach((tab)=>{
    if(tab.url){
        chrome.tabs.update(tab.id,{url: tab.url});
     }
    });
});
```

you can change the parameter object to fetch only active tabs as `{status:'complete', active: true}` refer to [query api of chrome extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query)

Reason for not using `chrome.tabs.reload` :

If the tab properties especially the tab.url have not changed, tab does not reload. If you want to force reload every time, it is better to update the tab URL with its own tab.url which sends the event of the change in property and tab automatically reloads.