# Auto reload a webpage when chrome extension is added

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to auto - reload a tab with URL, say 'www.example.com' as soon as I add a chrome extension in my browser.

I don't want to reload current tab but another tab with the URL 'www.example.com'.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [chrome extension API for refreshing the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8342756/chrome-extension-api-for-refreshing-the-page)

Comment: Use the above mentioned API with [`chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onInstalled).

Comment: Thanks for your reply @PredatorIWD. I used `chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener` and invoked a function on installation of app. Can you please help me to get a particular tab id for a webpage with URL "www.example.com" because when I am adding the extension, I am on different tab.

Comment: I got the answer to my query in above comment in [How to reload certain tab in chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48220101/how-to-reload-certain-tab-in-chrome-extension)